# Object inside of Object

Tags: oop

What is it called when an object has an object of the same type inside of itself?

Example:

```
public class Foo{

     public Foo myFoo;

}
```

Comment: Sorry for this, I couldn't resist.  Yo Dawg, I heard you liked objects so we I put an object in your object, so you could object while you object.

Comment: kibbee, a +1 doesn't suffice to explain how much i lolled at that simple comment right there...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think there's any specific name for this.  Although this concept is used in many different common programming constructs.  For instance, when representing a graph, tree, or linked list, the nodes usually have references to other nodes that they are linked/connected to.

Comment: Yes I'd call it a tree or a list or whatever its shape is.

Answer (score 5):

It means that `Foo` is a 'recursive data structure'.  Examples of this are trees, graphs, linked lists, etc.  There aren't many significant programs written that don't use at least some recursive structures, e.g. in any SQL server implementation it's pretty common that the query plan that gets executed will be defined in a similar way.  As a tiny example, the `WHERE` clause might get translated to a `FilterNode` that acts on data received from some other `Node` (like a table scan):

```
public interface Node { }

public class FilterNode implements Node {
    public Node underlyingNode;
    public Condition filterCondition;
}
```

In many cases the overall structure forms a directed acyclic graph, which means it's easy to safely traverse it recursively.  But if it's got cycles then you need to be careful that you don't get into infinite recursion (which is what another answer above is humorously warning about).

Answer (score 4):

Recursive containment.... :)

Comment: Yes, there is also the term "recursive composition" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Recursive_composition)

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Kibbee said, this is a type of a composite pattern